# How do you make a for loop increment by 1 each time

Tags: perl, for-loop

I have a Perl loop

```
my $i = 0;
    for ($i = 4, $i < 11, $i++) {
        print "$i\n";
    }
```

and I don't know why but instead of printing out
4
5
6 
7
8
9
10 
all on separate lines to my console it just prints out 5 5 5 and then terminates

Comment: Use `;` instead of `,`

Answer (score 1):

Perl uses semicolons to delimit arguments for a for loop.

Try this:

```
my $i = 0;
for ($i = 4; $i < 11; $i++) {
    print "$i\n";
}
```

Comment: Typically we don't answer typo questions. Comment instead and vote for closing because of a typo.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Got it, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Perl has two types of `for` loop, the [classic C style version](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#For-Loops) (`for (INIT; COND; STEP)`) and the [list iteration version](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops) (`for VAR (LIST)`).

You were trying to use the first form, but your code doesn't contain `;`, so Perl parses it as the second form; i.e. it's trying to iterate over the elements of the list `$i = 4, $i < 11, $i++`, which evaluates to `4, 1, 4` and sets `$i` to `5`.

In detail: `$i = 4` evaluates to `4` and sets `$i` to `4` as a side effect. `$i < 11` compares the value of `$i` (currently `4`) to `11`, which evaluates to `1` (true). `$i++` evaluates the the current value of `$i` (`4`) and increments `$i` as a side effect, setting it to `5`.

You didn't specify a loop variable, so Perl uses `$_` by default.

However, your loop body doesn't use `$_` at all and just prints the final value of `$i` in each iteration, which is `5`. You can see a bit better what's going on if you print `$_` instead:

```
for ($i = 4, $i < 11, $i++) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

```
4
1
4
```

To get the results you want, either write `for ($i = 4; $i < 11; $i++)` or convert fully to the list iteration variant:

```
for my $i (4 .. 10) {
    print "$i\n";
}
```

Comment: This is probably way too much detail for the OP, which buries the lede:  `for my $i (4 .. 10) { }` is much simpler and cleaner.